# UITableViewCell Separator disappearing in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have some strange issue with `UITableView` only in iOS 7.

`UITableViewCellSeparator` disappears above the first row and below the last row. Sometimes after selecting the rows or some scrolling actions it appears.

In my case `tableView` is loaded from the `Storyboard` with `UITableViewStylePlain` style. The problem is surely not in `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle`, which is not changed from default `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`.

As I read at ***Apple Dev Forums*** (*[here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/889468#889468) and [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/885634#885634)*) other people have such problem and some workarounds are found, for example:

```
Workaround: disable the default selection and recreate the behaviour in a method
trigged by a tapGestureRecognizer.
```

But I am still searching for the reason of such separator strange behaviour.

Any ideas?

**Update:** As I saw in XCode 5.1 DP and iOS 7.1 beta, Apple tried to fix this problem. Now separator is shown as needed sometimes below the last row, after some refreshing, but not after tableview creation.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like iOS7 is so immature. This and the long list of things that I have here show how far iOS7 is from perfection of previous iOSs.

Comment: The Settings app by Apple has the same problem, so I believe this is an iOS 7 issue. I have reported it, and in their followup they asked for images showing the issue.

Comment: @Gatada Where in the Settings app are you seeing the issue?

Comment: My issue occurs when the table begins editing (cell content shifts right and red circles appear) the separators vanish. I've tried all the suggestions listed at the time of this positing and none work for me.

I just downloaded 7.0.4 and still have the issue. I have one device running 7.0.2 and have no issues with separators at all (same build of my code). My 7.0.2 device is non Retina and my 7.0.3/7.0.4 device is Retina, so it could be related to the screen scale and not the iOS build.

Comment: Digging deeper, using Reveal App I was able to "tweak" the UITableView separator style at runtime (from singleLine to none, then back to singleLine) and the missing separators reappear. So it definitely appears to be a draw order thing, which seems right given some of the workarounds that others have used to get around this issue.

Comment: My tableView row height is 60 in the NIB (I've tried using 60.0 by overriding tableView: heightForRowAtIndex:). Using Reveal I can see that on the iOS 7.0.2/non retina device my cell content size gets forced by the OS to 59.0 and the OS's internal separatorView is located at 59.5 with a height of 0.5. 

On iOS 7.0.4/retina device my cell content size is forced to 59.5 and the separatorView is located at 59.75 with a height of 0.5.

Comment: Encountered the same issue and fixed by adding the following line in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Encountered the same issue and fixed by adding    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsFromString(@"1")];    with in  (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  method

Comment: Happened to me when I set the selectionStyle of the cells to "None". I just disabled selection on the whole table and that worked for me as an interim solution.

Comment: Adding an empty footer view also seems to be a workaround. Like that : `tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];`

Comment: This still appears to be broken in the iOS 8.0 betas. I've opened radar 17724043 should anyone care to dup it.

Comment: Please check this answer it solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/56341369/8201581

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I dumped the subview hierarchy of affected cells and found that the `_UITableViewCellSeparatorView` was set to hidden. No wonder it's not shown!

I overrode `layoutSubviews` in my `UITableViewCell` subclass and now the separators are displayed reliably:

**Objective-C**:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
            subview.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift**:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    guard let superview = contentView.superview else {
        return
    }
    for subview in superview.subviews {
        if String(subview.dynamicType).hasSuffix("SeparatorView") {
            subview.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

The other solutions proposed here didn't work consistently for me or seem clunky (adding custom 1 px footer views).

Comment: I have used your method but not in subclass I had added a category to UITableViewCell. It helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's also possible in a category. Since this requires method swizzling, I went for the simple subclass approach.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. My problem popped up whe the UITableView had enough rows to be scrollable. That "hasSuffix:" part is quite fragile though.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe question is silly, but isn't this using of Private API ?

Comment: Technically it's not using private API and your app won't be rejected because of this. It relies on an implementation detail though and could break in a future iOS version.

Comment: @Foriger if you worry of using  **hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"**, try to replace it with  **if(CGRectGetHeight(subview.frame) < 1.1)**. It probably even would work faster whether you don't use any other 1px custom views  in your cell. I chose 1.1px 'cos in Retina UITableViewSeparator has 0.5 points height, but for non-Retina it could be 1.0.

Comment: Works for me, grouped UITableView (iOS 7 and iOS8).

Comment: Although this mostly fixed the problem for me, for some reason one of my separators was still disappearing. Combining this fix with the toggling of `tableView.separatorStyle` suggested in other answers (which by itself made no difference for me) made it work for all of the separators.

Answer (score 42):

This worked for me:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // fix for separators bug in iOS 7
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Comment: You deserve more up votes, this is exactly what I needed, I added it in a category, so now after I do [tableView reloadData], if this bug happens (in my case the footer separator that was hidden is reappearing), I call [tableView reloadSeparators];

Answer (score 12):

I also had the problem with missing separator and I found out that the problem only occured when **`heightForRowAtIndexPath`** was **returning a decimal number**. Solution:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return ceil(yourHeight) // Ceiling this value fixes disappearing separators
}
```

Comment: What about the case if I do not implement even heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Interesting. However, it happens in my project as well - and heightForRowAtIndexPath isn't implemented. In IB row/cell height is 100.

Comment: It did not solve the issue for me and I do have the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Solves the issue at least partially. The cell does seem to be confused about non-integer heights.

Comment: You need to ceil the number of pixels and then divide by screen scale factor to get points which is okay to be in decimal. If you don't do this, it won't be retina optimized.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try adding a UIView of height 1 in the header and the footer of the table with light gray background color? Basically it'll mock the first and last separators.

Comment: this sounds good, but how exactly do you do this? use viewforfooter?

Comment: isn't as easy as it sounds, for some reason i had to also implement heightforfooter otherwise the height specified in the initwithframe was ignored.  i also notice though that the lightgraycolor is not the same color so this won't really work. might have to make a custom gray

Comment: that's pretty janky IMO

Comment: Yeah I fully agree. It's the sole workaround I found right after iOS 7's release, is there any better approach now?

Comment: To match the color, use tableView.separatorColor

Answer (score 8):

@samvermette

I fixed the problem by using this delegate methods. Now it doesn't flicker:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // fix for separators bug in iOS 7
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // fix for separators bug in iOS 7
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

We encountered this issue in our app. When the user selected a cell, a new table view was pushed onto the navigation controller stack and then when the user popped it off, the separator was missing. We solved it by putting `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` table view delegate method.

Comment: Have you tried `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;`?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an easier (although a bit messy) workaround if you need one, try selecting and deselecting the cell after the data is reloaded and the default animation is done.

just add:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

Comment: This workaround fixed it for me; however, I reversed it - to retain the selection. So, first deselect, then re-select.

Comment: I don't know what to override when you say "after the data is reloaded"

Answer (score 6):

I've found that the easiest solution is to, after reloading a cell, also reload the cell above:

```
if (indexPath.row > 0) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. Any other methods didn't help me (include separator style change from samvermette's answer).

Answer (score 4):

## A simple and clean solution that works on both iOS 8 and iOS 9 (beta 1)

Here is a simple, **clean** and non-intrusive workaround. It involves calling a category method that will fix the separators.

All you need to do is to walk down the hierarchy of the cell and un-hide the separator. Like this:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.superview.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
        subview.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

What I recommend is to add this to a category on UITableViewCell, like this:

```
@interface UITableViewCell (fixSeparator)
- (void)fixSeparator;
@end

@implementation UITableViewCell (fixSeparator)

- (void)fixSeparator {
    for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
            subview.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Because the separator can disappear in different cell than the one currently selected, it's probably a good idea to call this fix on *all* cells in the table view. For that, you can add a category to UITableView that goes like this:

```
@implementation UITableView (fixSeparators)

- (void)fixSeparators {
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.visibleCells) {
        [cell fixSeparator];
    }
}

@end
```

With this in place, you can call `-fixSeparatos` on your tableView right after the action that causes them to disappear. In my case, it was after calling `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`.

As I stated at the beginning, I've tested this on both iOS 8 and iOS 9. I presume it will work even on iOS 7 but I don't have a way to try it there. As you are probably aware, this does fiddle with internals of the cell so it could stop working in some future release. And Apple could theoretically (0.001% chance) reject your app because of this, but I can't see how they could even find out what you are doing there (checking the suffix of a class can't be detected by static analyzers as something bad, IMO).

Comment: YES.  This worked for me, after converting over to latest version of Swift.  ++ for calling fixSeparators after every call to tableView.endUpdates().

Comment: I am glad this was helpful to you! I really believe this is the best solution, so hopefully more people will discover it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @ortwin-gentz's comment, this solution works for me in iOS 9.

```swift
func fixCellsSeparator() {

    // Loop through every cell in the tableview
    for cell: UITableViewCell in self.tableView.visibleCells {

        // Loop through every subview in the cell which its class is kind of SeparatorView
        for subview: UIView in (cell.contentView.superview?.subviews)!
            where NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder).hasSuffix("SeparatorView") {
                subview.hidden = false
        }
    }

}
```

(Swift code)

I use *fixCellsSeparator()* function after calling *endUpdates()* in some methods of my tableView, for example:

```swift
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //  Perform some stuff
    //  ...

    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.fixCellsSeparator()

}
```

I hope this solution will be helpfull for someone!

Answer (score 2):

Complement to the answer of airpaulg.

So basically one has to implement two UITableDelegate methods. Here's my solution which works on both iOS7 and iOS6.

```
#define IS_OS_VERSION_7 (NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 < floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber))

#define UIColorFromRGB(hexRGBValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hexRGBValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hexRGBValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hexRGBValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

// This will hide the empty table grid below the cells if they do not cover the entire screen

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = nil;

    if (IS_OS_VERSION_7 /* && <is this the last section of the data source> */)
    {
        CGFloat height = 1 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., 320., height)];
        view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xC8C7CC);
        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        view = [UIView new];
    }
    return view;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (IS_OS_VERSION_7 /* && <is this the last section of the data source> */)
    {
        return 1 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    }
    else
    {
        // This will hide the empty table grid below the cells if they do not cover the entire screen
        return 0.01f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the issue for me:

Make sure `clipsToBounds` is set to YES for the cell, but NO for the cell's `contentView`. Also set `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: Setting clipSubviews to false in the storyboard for both the cell and the contentView fixed the issue! Needs more up votes!

Comment: Setting clipsToBounds to YES on the cells was enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this issue manifests under so many circumstances.

For me it had something to do with cell selection. I have no idea why and didn't have time to dig into it too deep, but I can say it started occurring when I set the cell's `selectionStyle` to none. ie:

```
//This line brought up the issue for me
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I tried using some of the delegate methods above that toggle on and off the `separatorStyle`  property of the `tableView` but they didn't seem to do anything to fix my issue.

The whole reason why I needed that was because I didn't even need cell selection.

So, I did find something that worked for me. I just disabled selection on the `UITableView`:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Hope this helps someone, if you don't need to have cell selection.

Answer (score 2):

I tried so many suggestions to fix but cannot fix that.Finally I decided to custom separator line as below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var lineView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 20, 1))

    lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 170.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(lineView)
}
```

**P/S:** custom at **willDisplayCell** NOT **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

Answer (score 1):

Quite surprisingly, changing cell's `separatorInset` value back and forth seems to be working:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [self.controller.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[self.controller.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath animated:YES];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.controller.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath];
UIEdgeInsets insets = cell.separatorInset;
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, insets.left + 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
cell.separatorInset = insets;
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the above issue, add empty footer in viewDidLoad.

```
UIView *emptyView_ = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];   
emptyView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
[tableView setTableFooterView:emptyView_];
```

Please don't use the above lines in viewForFooterInSection delegate method. Means Dont implement viewForFooterInSection method.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem of this inconsistent separator line display at the bottom of my UITableView.
Using a custom footer view, I have been able to create a similar line and to display it on top of the potential existing one (which was sometimes missing).

The only problem of this solution is that Apple may change one day the thickness of the line

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    float w = tableView.frame.size.width;

    UIView * footerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, 1)];
    footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    footerView.clipsToBounds=NO;

    UIView* separatoraddon = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -.5, w, .5)];
    separatoraddon.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    separatoraddon.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor;
    [footerView addSubview:separatoraddon];

    return footerView;
}
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved putting these lines of code where the update of the tableview hapens:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
```

For example, in my case i've putted them here:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove a cell selection before you doing cell's update. Then you could restore selection.

```
NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath animated:NO];
    [self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ path ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

to expand on airpaulg answer, because it didn't entirely work for me..

i had to also implement the heightforfooter method to get the height

then i noticed the lightgraycolor is too dark. i fixed this by grabbing the current separator color of the tableview and using that:

`UIColor *separatorGray = [self.briefcaseTableView separatorColor];
    [footerSeparator setBackgroundColor:separatorGray];`

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem in our project. My table view had a tableFooterView which could make this happen. I found the separator below the last row would appear if I removed that tableFooterView.

Answer (score 0):

What made the difference for me was reloading the row for which the bottom separator line would not appear:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = 
     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:sectionIndex];  
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in another way: add a layer that its height is 0.5px and its color is lightgray into tableview.tableFooterView as its sublayer.

the code is just like this:

```
UIView *tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];
CALayer *topSeperatorLine = [CALayer layer];
topSeperatorLine.borderWidth = 0.5f;
topSeperatorLine.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
topSeperatorLine.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0.5f);
[tableFooterView.layer addSublayer:topSeperatorLine];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = tableFooterView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableViewCell Subclass implement layoutSubviews and add:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews]
    for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
            CGRect separatorFrame = subview.frame;
            separatorFrame.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
            subview.frame = separatorFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned, this problem seems to manifest in a variety of ways.  I resolved my issue via the following workaround:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through the answers and solutions I came up with such observations:

This seems to be problematic in both iOS 7 and 8. I noticed the problem when selecting cell from code in `viewDidLoad` method so:

1) workaround was doing so in `viewDidAppear:` if someone doesn't mind the noticeable delay between presenting the view and selecting the cell

2) [the second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23498566/3151066) worked for me but the code looks a bit fragile as it base on the internal implementation of the `UITableViewCell`

3) adding own separator seems to be the most flexible and best for now but require more coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the style in `viewWillAppear` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As this is still an issue with IOS 8, I will add my solution in Swift. Set the tableview separator line to none. Then add this code to the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. It will add a nice separator. The if statement allows to decide which cells should have a separator.

```
    var separator:UIView!
    if let s = cell.viewWithTag(1000)
    {
        separator = s
    }
    else
    {
        separator = UIView()
        separator.tag = 1000
        separator.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        cell.addSubview(separator)

        // Swiper constraints
        var leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: separator, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
        var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: separator, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.5)
        var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: separator, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant:0)
        var trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: separator, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
        cell.addConstraints([bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, heightConstraint, trailingConstraint])
    }

    if indexPath.row == 3
    {
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    else
    {
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this problem. After you insert your cell(s), reload the section. If reloading the entire section is too intensive for you, just reload the indexPaths above and below.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    //  Fix for issue where seperators disappear

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

ran into a similar problem, I found that another good solution, especially if your dataSource is not large is reload the tableData when you implement the `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method, here's an example:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      if (scrollView == self.tableView1) {
          [self.tableView1 reloadData];
      }

      else {
          [self.tableView2 reloadData];
      }
}
```

You can also just reload non-visible data based on the visible dataSource, but that requires some more hacking.

Keep in mind this delegate function falls under the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reloading the data after beginUpdates and endUpdates:

```
private func animateCellHeighChangeForTableView(tableView: UITableView, withDuration duration: Double) {
     UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) { () -> Void in
        tableView.beginUpdates();
        tableView.endUpdates();
        tableView.reloadData();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The disappearing separator problem happens when I insert/delete rows with an animation. What solved it for me was to invoke  `deselectRowAtIndexPath()`

```
var insertion = [NSIndexPath]()
var deletion = [NSIndexPath]()
// TODO: populate the insertion array and deletion array

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletion, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertion, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simple, clean, and efficient way** to do this without having to loop through every subview of a cell, which is called every time a cell is dequeued/created, is by using good ole KVC:

```
UIView *separatorView = [self valueForKey:@"separatorView"]; // pull separator using KVC

if (separatorView) {
    separatorView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Stick that in `layoutSubviews` of your cell class and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modified @Lee's Answer to get the default table view separator style and not to show separator for the last row which is odd. Hope it helps somebody.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row >= yourDataSource.count - 1{
                return
        }

        let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 0.5))
        lineView.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
        cell.contentView.addSubview(lineView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried all the listed answers but was not working for me, I used two answers, which worked for me. below is the solution:

add the below lines in your UITableViewConstroller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       // fix for separators bug in iOS 7
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine;
}
```

Now, override the below method in UITableViewCell

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    guard let superview = contentView.superview else {
        return
    }
    for subview in superview.subviews {
        if String(describing: type(of: subview)).hasSuffix("SeparatorView") {
            subview.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for others as well. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

One and only fix: Write the below lines of code above @implementation of .m file from which the tableView exists.

```
@interface UITableViewCell (fixSeparator)
- (void)layoutSubviews;

@end

@implementation UITableViewCell (fixSeparator)

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
            subview.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem by setting in IB: Separator Inset = custom, left = 0, right = 0