# In UITableView disappears separator when scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In UITableView disappears separator when scrolling

IOS 7.0 (simulator and iphone)

Code from example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924589/uitableviewcell-separator-disappearing-in-ios7

Comment: @propstm This is quite a different problem

Comment: I Have checked its working fine can you paste your code have you made any changes?

Comment: @nullproduction its working fine at my end i have checked it.

Comment: @Divz Have you tried after select cells to scroll down and back?

Comment: @nullproduction yes i have checked

Comment: you are correct. it does remove the separators after scrolling, i believe this is something that should be reported as a bug to apple, otherwise it seems to create a different view for the cells selected which might be what they intended to do with table view in iOS 7.

Comment: its overlap issue, check the subviews.

Comment: @XCode Monkey I created a thread a week ago but got no response https://devforums.apple.com/message/952146#952146