# UITableViewCell changing height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change height of the touched row in table view (so it expands):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    if let currentSelection = self.currentSelection {
        if currentSelection == indexPath {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            self.currentSelection = nil
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
            setupAnimation(cell, hide: true) //Custom animation inside the cell
        }
    } else {
        self.currentSelection = indexPath
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
        setupAnimation(cell, hide: false) //Custom animation inside the cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let currentSelection = self.currentSelection {
        if indexPath == currentSelection {
            return 80.0
        }
    }
    return 50.0
}
```

This is working - the height changes to 80.0 when I tap the row, and comes back to 50.0 when I tap it again. The thing is that my separator is not moving.

Not only it is not moving, but when I tap the cell:

1. the height expands ->
2. the tapped cell separator stays in the same place ->
3. the separator of the cell above disappears

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I have tried to override layoutSubviews method and forgot about that - I didn't call super.layoutSubviews() in it. Now the separator of selected cell is moving down with it but I still have problem with the separator of the cell above disappearing

Answer (score 2):

try to reload that cell

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) //try other animations
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: In CustomTableViewCell class in method `awakeFromNib` try `self.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: I'm so stupid. I tried to override layout subviews but didn't call super in that method. Now the separator of selected cell is moving down, but I still have problem with separator of the above cell disappearing

Comment: Did try it, it didn't have effect on the separator not moving down, and neither  has it on the existing problem

Comment: can u share screenshot ? that will be more helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924589/uitableviewcell-separator-disappearing-in-ios7

Comment: The solutions don't work for me. I don't know - maybe it does something to do with that I set up cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None  in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: may be just try commenting that line.
are u checking this on simulator or device. if simulator then check on 100% scale

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to have your cell selected this thread should be the answer:

[UITableView separator line disappears when selecting cells in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212476/uitableview-separator-line-disappears-when-selecting-cells-in-ios7)